# How to tweak skills bar to show "out of 5" instead of "out of 6"?

Tags: formatting, bar-chart

I am quite new to LaTeX and have been using it mostly to write up my assignments. I have since taken on the challenge to re-write my resume using LaTeX too and I have grown quite fond of the twentyseondscv template, which can be found [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv).

The template is mostly quite user-friendly, even for a novice like myself, but I have one small issue - the resume allows for skills to be shown as a score, out of 6, and this score is translated into a bar. For example, if you had a skill with a score of 6, it would colour the entire bar.

The code for the template is extremely long, so I reproduce the portion of the code relating to the skills bars below:

```
\newcommand\skills[1]{ 
    \renewcommand{\skills}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
                \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
                \draw[fill=white,mainblue](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
                \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
```

However, I find that a score, out of 6, is rather "weird" and would like it to be out of 5 instead. I tried to play around with the code, such as by changing the "6" to a "5", but that merely shortens the bar - it simply removes the last 1/6 of the bar. **Instead, what I want is for the bar to be the same length, but for it to be "cut" into 5 portions, instead of 6, such that if I put a skill of a score of 1, it should shade 1/5 of the bar, not 1/6, which it currently does.**

How can I tweak the code above to reflect this? I would suppose the change(s) should be very minor and easy, although as mentioned at the start, I am very new to LaTeX, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I cannot test this, as I cannot access the template, but usually the default length in tikz is 1cm. You can change the 6 to 5 and add ‘[y=1.2cm]’ after ‘\begin[tikzpicture]’. That should stretch it to the original length but calculate everything out of 5.

Comment: @MarkusG. Oh yes! Thank you so much! Your answer was not quite right - adding `[y=1.2cm]` increased the width of the bar, not the length, so I obviously tried `[x=1.2cm]` and then it worked, but yes, you solved my issue nonetheless! :) I have posted an edit with credits to you!

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I keep messing x and y up. Glad I could help.

Comment: Instead of adding the answer to the question, I suggest either @MarkusG. or yourself add a "proper" answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, that is probably wiser and I have done so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, here my answer, with a comparison of the original code and the “out of 5” version.

As I mentioned in the comments above, the default length for tikz is 1cm in both x and y directions. They can be modified by adding the respective options to the environment. To get from out of 6 to out of 5, but with the original length, you need a factor of 1.2. Hence, adding the option `x=1.2cm` stretches everything by the required amount.
Additionally, the maximum length of the rectangle needs to be shortened from 6 to 5 to account for the changes.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

%The original command
\newcommand\skillsorig[1]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
           \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
                \draw[fill=gray,gray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
                \draw[fill=white,blue](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
                \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
            }
       \end{tikzpicture}
}

%The new command
\newcommand\skills[1]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.2cm]
           \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
                \draw[fill=gray,gray] (0,\i) rectangle (5,\i+0.4);
                \draw[fill=white,blue](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
                \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
            }
       \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    %Out of 6
    \skillsorig{{name/4.8}}
    
    %Out of 5
    \skills{{name/4}}
\end{document}
```

Note that I removed the renewcommand part of the code as it is not required outside of the template and replaced the colours with default ones.